# a function in a language with closures that takes varying actions depending on a variable defined outside

Tags: lua, closures

In a language that supports closures (Lua in this case) is there any way I can check for the value of the outside variable without passing it as a variable into the function?

When I do the below:

```
local a = 100

local function checkAAndDoSomething()
    print(a * 10)
end

checkAAndDoSomething()
local a = 200
checkAAndDoSomething()
```

I get:

```
1000
1000
```

The solution I figured out is passing the variable as a parameter into the function explicitly, as in

```
local function checkAAndDoSomething(a)
    print(a * 10)
end
```

Then everything works as "expected" coming from a non closure background.

Just wanted to confirm, is my reasoning above correct? Is this (passing the variable explicitly) the only / best way of going about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your code didn't change the value is because you *re-declared* the variable `a`. If you do this instead:

```
local a = 100

local function checkAAndDoSomething()
    print(a * 10)
end

checkAAndDoSomething()
a = 200
checkAAndDoSomething()
```

You get the output you were expecting:

```
1000
2000
```

I can't comment much on what the best way of doing something is, as it's highly dependent on the situation. I tend to go for explicit arguments, but my situations could be completely different from yours.

Comment: oh wow, completely missed the redeclaration, thank you! :) guess need to read up on closures again to really understand what they do...

Comment: "Re-declared the variable" suggests there is one variable. There are actually two; Just one shadows the other. In code where the second's ended before the first's, the first would be accessible by name again.